# Explain the last line of this proof (it's an identity I can't figure out)?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, summation, binomial-theorem

I can't understand the equality in equation 4 [in this paper](http://ac.els-cdn.com/0097316590900644/1-s2.0-0097316590900644-main.pdf?_tid=be1847a2-d2d0-11e5-b34c-00000aacb35e&acdnat=1455423149_19ff061d2db90ce74964537530190cef).

I understand everything up until that point. I see how $$j \binom{n-p}{j}=(n-s)\binom{n-s-1}{j-1}$$ but I'm not sure how they used that and the binomial identity (I'm not sure which identity they are referring to) to show the equation in eq. 4, that is: $$ \sum_{j=0}^{n-s}\binom{n-s}{j}(s+j-1)(n-1)^{n-s-j-1}=sn^{n-s-1}$$
Can anyone help me understand this last part of their proof? Why is this equation true? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put $n-s-j=r$:

$$\begin{align}
\sum_{j=0}^{n-s}\binom {n-s}j(s+j-1)(n-1)^{n-s-j-1}
&=\sum_{r=0}^{n-s}\binom{n-s}{n-s-r}(n-r-1)(n-1)^{r-1}\\\\
&=\sum_{r=0}^{n-s}\binom {n-s}r(n-1)^r-\sum_{r=0}^{n-s}\binom {n-s}r r(n-1)^{r-1}\\\\
&=[1+(n-1)]^{n-s}-(n-s)n^{n-s-1}\\\\
&=n^{n-s}-(n-s)n^{n-s-1}\\\\
&=sn^{n-s-1}\quad\blacksquare
\end{align}$$

---

Some additional notes which may be useful in reading the above:

When substituting $n-s-j=r$, notice that when $j=0, r=n-s$ and when $j=n-s, r=0$ so limits are the same (but inverted).

The following identities are useful:
$$\sum_{r=0}^m \binom mr x^r=(1+x)^m\\
\sum_{r=0}^{m}\binom mr rx^{r-1}=m(1+x)^{m-1}$$
Substitute $m=n-s$ and $x=n-1$ and the result unfolds before your eyes!

Comment: How did you substitute $n-j$ with $n-s$?  I see how it's $s+r$ but not how that's $n-s$.  It must have something to do with how you start the sum at $r=0$ but I don't follow that either.  Maybe you can include another step or two?

Comment: Ah I didn't notice what GregoryGrant pointed out. I agree, would you mind adding a few extra steps @hypergeometric ? :)

Comment: This is as far as I can get when I substitute in $r$:

$$\sum_{r=0}^{n-s} \binom{r+s}{n-s-r}(n-r-1)(n-1)^{r-1}$$

Comment: @GregoryGrant: It was a typo, but now corrected! It should be $n-s$ per original question.  Thanks.

Comment: @User - Let me add some notes. How did you get the equation shown in the comment?

Comment: @User - Additional notes added. See if these help.